# How to prevent a Gtk widget from being "grayed out" when set insensitive?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I am using a Gtk EventBox which holds an image to receive mouse click events on the image. Once the image is clicked, the EventBox is set insensitive. However, since this results in the EventBox being "grayed out", the colors of my image become pale as well. I really don't like this. Is there any way to disable this kind of behaviour of Gtk widgets?

Code example:

```
var ebox = new EventBox ();
var img = new Image ();
img.set_from_file ("my_image.png");
img.show ();
ebox.add (img);

ebox.button_press_event.connect ( () => { ebox.set_sensitive (false); return true; } );
```

Comment: Why not block or disconnect the event handler instead of making the widget insensitive?

Comment: @Rawing It would make it more complicated and since the method exists, I thought that was the way to do it.

Comment: Ok, so I decided to go with blocking and unblocking the signal handler. Since Vala Gtk code examples are so hard to find, here is roughly what I used:
`handler_id = ebox.button_press_event.connect ( () => { callback_function (); return true; } );
GLib.SignalHandler.block (ebox, handler_id);
GLib.SignalHandler.unblock (ebox, handler_id);`

Answer (score 0):

you could subclass the widget, add a virtual method do_draw(), and draw your image there.